# WARNING: recursion requested but not available, 3 servers only one fails

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, bind

- Primary nameserver at pp.pp.pp.pp
- Secondary namseserver ss.ss.ss.ss
- third namserver at tt.tt.tt.tt

> ```
> primary named.conf
> acl "trusted" {
>   ss.ss.ss.ss;
>   tt.tt.tt.tt;
>   localhost;
> };
> ```

from third

> dig @pp.pp.pp.pp www.google.com

I get answers.

But from the secondary:

> dig @pp.pp.pp.pp www.google.com

I get 
WARNING: recursion requested but not available
and no answer.

If I comment out the third server in the primary's named.conf trusted section, and rndc reload, I get the WARNING: recursion requested but not available.  Uncomment, rndc reload, re-dig, warning it goes away.

The primary sees the secondary as external apparently and is not obeying the trusted setting.

Appreciate any suggestions to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, which leads to a different question.

The secondary server is sending it's query from it's secondary IP address.  It has a secondary on the same interface (eth0:1).

I added that to the trusted lists and it cured the DNS lookup.

But why is it querying from the secondary IP instead of the primary?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix for that, too.

in cfg-eth0 after gateway, add:
METRIC=1
And in cfg:eth0:1
METRIC=999

reboot.  cured.

Answer (score 0):

And found the probably better answer.  Remove the gateway from the alias file (*:1) and do not use the metric setting.  Seems to fix it as well.  I gather 2 gateways are bad